# Use resolve (or any data) in states custom data

Tags: angular-ui-router

Using angular 1.2 and ui-router 2.8

Was wondering if it was possible to inject data from either the resolve or $scope into a states custom data object. I know I can alter this data in a controller "$state.$current.data.key = value;" but this will not inherent to children.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about using the custom data the way you're asking - I haven't done that and I can't find an example of it in the docs.

You could define a resolve dependency on the parent, and the child will have access to it as long as it's injected as a dependency within the child as well. See [this UI-Router wiki page](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views#wiki-inherited-resolved-dependencies) for an example.